# Why won't "falling_block" work in minecraft bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

`summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ {Block:stone,Time:1,Passengers...` is a part of a command but this part won't work and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because Bedrock Edition doesn't have the same support for NBT data that Java Edition has.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the only nbt tags in bedrock edition are `Can_Place` and `Can_Destroy` so I don't think that command would work.

Comment: Is it intentional that both of your NBT tags in your answer are `can place on`?

Comment: It's not actually NBT, it's JSON (which looks very similar). And with that spelling it wouldn't work.