# How can I summon falling block on Switch?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

I've tried summoning it but it won't work. I'm on Switch too, so I guess that's why.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The console you're using shouldn't affect the result of a command, as far as I know.

Comment: Possble duplicate of [Why won't "falling\_block" work in minecraft bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/365685/why-wont-falling-block-work-in-minecraft-bedrock)